# NIST Framework Cyber Security Maturity Assessment

Tags: nist

How can I assess customer cyber security posture based on NIST framework and provide scoring? What is the easiest approach, milestones, steps to do it - I know that I need to ask questions and then map the answers to the criteria of each control and determine whether the control is partially met or not.

Comment: Have you done any research? Are you aware that NIST provides guidance on this very question? Googling "NIST framework assessment" returns a lot of useful material.